# ezPublish - fetch objects published between dates

Tags: ezpublish

I need to `fetch` articles (or objects) published between "now" and "a month before". Code looks like this:

```
{def $date = currentdate()}
{def $day = currentdate()|datetime( 'custom', '%d' )}
{def $month = currentdate()|datetime( 'custom', '%m' )}
{def $year = currentdate()|datetime( 'custom', '%Y' )}
{def $fromDate = maketime(0,0,0,$month|dec(), $day, $year)}

{def $items = fetch(content, list, hash(
    'parent_node_id', 10,
    'attribute_filter', array('and', 
                                    array('article/publish_date', '<=', $data),
                                    array('article/publish_date', '>', $fromDate),
                                    array( 'priority', '>=', 0 )),                           
    'class_filter_type',    'include',
    'class_filter_array',   array('article')
))}
```

Unfortunately, nothing comes out. When I remove the `$fromDate` array from the `fetch`, it works.

Comment: which version of ezpublish are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

In short, your template fetch code is inaccurate (either here or in your template).

The line, "array('article/publish_date', '<=', $data)," should be "array('article/publish_date', '<=', $date)," instead to fix the variable typo.

Also your date timestamp comparison logic (operator) usage is also incorrect (I think). It has been a while since I last did what you are doing but when I did it last I used the following logic instead.

```
{* Example: http://example/layout/set/content_statistics.csv/(startDate)/2010-07-14/(endDate)/2010-07-19/ *}
{def $articles=false()}

{if and( is_set( $view_parameters.startDate ), is_set( $view_parameters.endDate ) )}

{def $startDate=$view_parameters.startDate|explode("-")
$endDate=$view_parameters.endDate|explode("-")}

{def $startDateTimestamp=maketime(0,0,0,$startDate.1,$startDate.2,$startDate.0)
$endDateTimestamp=maketime(23,59,59,$endDate.1,$endDate.2,$endDate.0)}

{set $articles=fetch( 'content', 'list', hash(
     'parent_node_id', 77,
     'class_filter_type', 'include',
     'class_filter_array', array( 'article' ),
     'sort_by', array( 'published', false() ),
     'attribute_filter', array( array( 'published', '>=', $startDateTimestamp ),
                                array( 'published', '<', $endDateTimestamp ) )
 ) )}
{else}

{set $articles=fetch( 'content', 'list', hash(
     'parent_node_id', 77,
     'class_filter_type', 'include',
     'class_filter_array', array( 'article' ),
     'sort_by', array( 'published', false() ),
     'limit', 10000
 ) )}
{/if}
```

Notice that the attribute filter date timestamp comparison operators use a very different formula, re: '>=' '<' and I think this example will work better for you.

```
     'attribute_filter', array( array( 'published', '>=', $startDateTimestamp ),
                                array( 'published', '<', $endDateTimestamp ) )
 ) )}
```

I hope this helps!

Cheers,
Heath

Note: I borrowed the above example from eZpedia but was afraid to link here as I am unsure of the policy of linking to community documentation (even when it has the answer to the question being asked): http://www.ezpedia.org/en/solution/how_to_fetch_content_based_on_view_parameter_date_range